# HotModuleReplacementPlugin and react-hot-loader both failing

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, react-hot-loader, hot-module-replacement

It's been blowing my mind figuring out the solution for these `webpack.config.js` issues I have. In the `entry` property, it says it can't find the directories defined; i tried to prepend `./node_modules/` since the packages are located in the `node_modules` folder, but it still failed. In the `plugins` property, it says:

> new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin is not a constructor

I tried to remove the `webpack` but it says:

> HotModuleReplacementPlugin is not defined

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, 'main/components/src')
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'main/components/build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: '/node_modules/'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'main/components/src'),
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'React App',
      filename: './main/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new webpack.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ]
}
```

I would very much appreciate the answer of anyone who could help me solve these issues.

Comment: Maybe try to install webpack again.. But do not remove "webpack."! Also do NOT prepend ./node_modules/. (it's ALL in there). Because of the very bad documentation its kinda tricky to set it up if you're new. Thats why I set up the "React-Junglebook" https://cheesyeyes.github.io/react-junglebook/
Simple clone 2. Melon which is a very clean setup for HMR support..

Comment: problem's already solved. Thanks for the suggestion, by the way